# Edit .profile file without using terminal

Tags: macos, path, .profile

I have edited the .profile file and I messed up something so that the PATH has changed and I can't use commands such as nano, sudo, etc...
The problem would be easy to solve because I know how to edit this file again to put the corrent path.But I can't use "sudo nano .profile" command because the PATH is messed up, and I can't see hidden files using finder.So how do I see hidden files with finder, why can't I see them? How to solve this ridicolous problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to simply move (mv) the bad .profile aside, so that you get the default path. Then once you have repaired the bad .profile move it back.

You can also manually override the path you get from your .profile, but the exact syntax for doing that depends on which shell you use. For bash, for example, you would do:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Notice that *mv* does not work without a proper PATH. `export` is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use explicit paths until you have fixed your `PATH` variable:

```
$ /usr/bin/nano ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Terminal type:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

killall Finder
```

By the way, you should be able to edit the file in your terminale by running:

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.profile
```

**UPDATE:**

if you can't use the terminal, download this: http://blacktree-secrets.googlecode.com/files/Secrets_1.0.6.zip

It's preference pane that lets you change some advanced options, among them there is also the "Show hidden files" in Finder.

(Source: http://secrets.blacktree.com/)

Comment: I can't use the terminal.

Comment: Why can't you use Terminal ? It should still work OK even if PATH is not set.

Comment: They're right. What's up with your terminal? What happens if you open it e.g. with Spotlight?

Comment: The purpose of editing the .profile file was that the PATH was messed up.So I could use the terminal, but not the bash commands.I exported the PATH manually like shown by the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm glad for you if you solved your problem, but still can't understand the -1 on my answer. You asked how to see hidden files on finder, and here I provide two ways to accomplish this..